# Не могу подключиться к базе данных через SQLDeveloper

Tags: база-данных, oracle, sqldeveloper

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных через SQLDeveloper. Ubuntu 16.

Появляется ошибка 17022 (скрин прикрепил.)

Читал в интернете, пишут, что надо клиента указать.... В настройках Advanced указал путь до JDBC Client Jar оракловского. Не помогло.

Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, скрин настроек подключения

Comment: Добавил. Указать настоящий Hostname не могу.

Comment: А прослушиватель на хосте запущен? Ошибка говорит, что соединение с ним невозможно установить.

Comment: Имеете ввиду, что не во мне причина, а в удаленной машине?

Comment: Пингуется ли удаленный хост? Получается ли подключитсья к порту например (в Виндовс можно телнетом, наверняка в убунте есть что-то похожее) ? Возможно у вас установлен оракловый клиент на вашей машине с убунту??

Comment: @ks_on_v ну да, база же на удалённой машине. Вы к ней доступ имеете?